# Any benefit to an Async method that Synchronously Loops a call

Tags: c#, loops, asynchronous, async-await

I'm writing a program that must pull data from an external api via an SDK.  I'm not well versed in await/async operations - but know the SDK for each of the calls offers an Async method. `GetResultsAsync<TObject>()`

Each query has a limit of records returned - so in order to get all records for the month - I must order by ID, and loop.  Here's some sample code of the current Synchronous calls out. As long as I get results - I check for more.

```
public List<TimeEntry> ListTimeEntries(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var page = 1;
    var hasMore = false;
    var qry = string.Format("timeStart >= [{0}] and timeEnd <= [{1}]", startDate, endDate); //For example
    var results = List<TimeEntry>();
    do
    {
        var newItems = api.GetEntries(qry, "id desc", maxPageSize, page).GetResults<List<TimeEntry>>();
        results.AddRange(newItems);
        hasMore = newItems.Any();
        page++;
    } while (hasMore);
    return results;
}
```

This could make up to say 4-5 loops (or more depending on dates), but is obviously time consuming.

If I simply convert this to an `async` method - would I be able to have other synchronous calls being made at the same time?  Let's assume I also need to get Service Tickets and Project Tickets for the same time period - but don't do any logical processing until all are returned.  Could I have all three calls running asynchronously?

**Here's the Goal**

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
var endDate = DateTime.Now;

var timeTask = ListTimeEntries(startDate, endDate);
var serviceTask = ListServiceTickets(startDate, endDate);
var projectTask = ListProjectTickets(startdDate, endDate);

var timeEntries = await timeTask;
var serviceTickets = await serviceTask;
var projectTickets = await projectTask;

// Do what ever processing logic I need now.
```

**How to Achieve?**

For **example #1** - would simply making the Method as `async` work?  EG:

```
public async Task<List<TimeEntry>> ListTimeEntries(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var page = 1;
    var hasMore = false;
    var qry = string.Format("timeStart >= [{0}] and timeEnd <= [{1}]", startDate, endDate); //For example
    var results = List<TimeEntry>();
    do
    {
        var newItems = api.GetEntries(qry, "id desc", maxPageSize, page).GetResults<List<TimeEntry>>();
        results.AddRange(newItems);
        hasMore = newItems.Any();
        page++;
    } while (hasMore);
    return results;
}
```

Or would there be any benefit for actually using the SDK's `GetResultsAsync<>` method such as **Example 2**:

```
public async Task<List<TimeEntry>> ListTimeEntries(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var page = 1;
    var hasMore = false;
    var qry = string.Format("timeStart >= [{0}] and timeEnd <= [{1}]", startDate, endDate); //For example
    var results = List<TimeEntry>();
    do
    {
        var newItemsTask = api.GetEntries(qry, "id desc", maxPageSize, page).GetResultsAsync<List<TimeEntry>>();
        var newItems = await newItemsTask;
        results.AddRange(newItems);
        hasMore = newItems.Any();
        page++;
    } while (hasMore);
    return results;
}
```

While I understand that these methods internally are still running Synchronously - I'm hoping to make each call to `ListTimeEntries`, `ListServiceTickets`, and `ListProjectTickets` happen asynchronously to speed up.

I guess my thought/hope - with lack of knowledge - would be that each Synchronous call would utilize a different thread - thus speeding up the overall process. Am I way off base?

Comment: What kind of app is this? Is `api.GetEntries` I/O bound and does it return a `Task<T>`? Those 2 questions determine if there is a benefit to using `async/await` and if you can use `async/await`. As for your final envisioned calling code you have to check if the api is also thread safe (supports multiple simultaneous calls). Not all APIs are, like Entity Framework's `DbContext` for example.

Comment: @Igor - yes `api.GetEntries` will return a `Task<T>` - because of the `GetResultsAsync<T>` call that executes it.

Comment: Then the code should be `var newItems = await api.GetEntries(...` and add the `async` keyword to the method signature that calls this and have it also return a `Task<T>`.

Comment: @Igor - I am essentially doing that in the second example (I edited to show it's a second example).  Is that the proper way then?

Comment: The second example seems correct. Calling `ListTimeEntries` multiple times without awaiting might not work, it depends on if the api is thread safe (supports concurrent calls). If it is not thread safe maybe one instance per method (where the api instance is local to the method) is thread safe but this really depends on the api in question.

Comment: Just FYI in the 'Heres the Goal' section you await each call. This means that the second call wont run until the first call is complete and 3rd until the second. If you want them all to be happening at the same time and then wait for them all to finish you need await `Task.WhenAll` passing in you're three tasks

Comment: @Dave - That code is making 3 calls where each call is returning a started task. Each task is then, in turn, awaited. Although `Task.WhenAll` might be a cleaner way to rewrite that code it is functionally equivalent to what is there now.

Comment: @Igor Sorry, I had misread the code, its been a long friday. OP please ignore my comment

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like the following. You will need to be aware of potential issues around API limits and of course there is the possibility for having at least three additional requests in-flight before all 4 threads complete - a small price to pay if you have lots of pages to retrieve.

```
public async Task<IList<TimeEntry>> CallSomething(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var qry = string.Format("timeStart >= [{0}] and timeEnd <= [{1}]", startDate, endDate); //For example

    const threadCount = 4;

    var isComplete = new ManualResetEvent();
    var page = 0;
    var results = new ConcurrentBag<TimeEntry>();
    var thread = new Task[threadCount];
    for(var i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
    {
        thread[i] = Task.Run(
            async () =>
            {
                while(!isComplete.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero))
                {
                    var localPage = Interlocked.Increment(ref page);

                    var newItems = await api
                        .GetEntries(qry, "id desc", maxPageSize, localPage)
                        .GetResultsAsync<List<TimeEntry>>()
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if (!newItems.Any())
                    {
                        isComplete.Set();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var item in newItems)
                        {
                            results.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        )
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(thread).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return results.OrderByDescending(f => f.Id).ToList();
}
```